# PyTest: Interactive Output (instead of pure ASCII)

Tags: python, pytest

How can I get expandable output from `PyTest`?

For example the local variables. It would be great if I could expand/collapse them depending on my need.

I think that's where the current text-output of `PyTest` reaches its limit.

The question: Is there a way to get an **interactive** output from `PyTest`?

With **interactive** I mean to be able to expand/collapse the local variables.

[image: expand-on-demand]

Above example is from the django debug page.

I would like to have such an interactive output if I run pytest.

My output looks like this:

[image: pytest-output-text-only]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For achieving an output similar to the screenshot (which I assume is from a Django debugging session), you will need pytest and the pytest-html plugin.

You invoke pytest using this command line.

```
pytest --showlocals --html=report.html --self-contained-html testmodule/test.py
```

This will give you a HTML report with a nice overview of collapsible tests. Passing the argument `--showlocals` will also be reflected in the HTML report. All failed tests will show the local variable scope.

I created a small [example repository](https://github.com/buzz/pytest-html-example) with further instructions.

[image: HTML report example]

Comment: This looks cool. Usually I call pytest via PyCharm. Can PyCharm display the HTML so that I can expand/collapse details?

Comment: Yes, PyCharm can [display HTML pages](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/viewing-pages-with-web-contents.html). You need **PyCharm Professional** for this to work though.

Comment: Also, you might want to consider other pytest plugins for improved Developer experience. [pytest-watch](https://github.com/joeyespo/pytest-watch) (automatically run tests on file save) and [pytest-testmon](https://testmon.org/) (run only tests that have changed code).

Comment: The repository looks good but the `test.py` file is missing. Even if trivial it should be included in the body of this answer. (Usual SO rules and format.) It may also be possible to include the HTML as a [snippet](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stack-snippets), which would add value for the readers.

Comment: What do you mean the `test.py` file is missing? It is in the repository for reference. The `test.py` is not substantial to the question or the answer. It could be any other pytest test case for that matter. So, I deliberately decided not to paste its contents as it would only clutter the answer. The same goes for the generated HTML. It is about 500 lines longs. There's no point in including it in the body of the answer.

Comment: This works, but the django debug page is much better than the pytest-html output. The django-debug-page makes a difference between my code and framework code and highlights my code (that's where the bugs are). You can expand/collapse per stacktrace frame. If you use a non-trivial example, then the pytest-html output still looks like ascii (the big gray <pre> areas).

Comment: @buzz I can create html output with PyCharm community, too. I just need to open the create file via `file:///...` in my browser.

Comment: @guettli I agree, the Django debug tools are prolific. pytest reports are not quite on par in terms of DX. I'm confident something similar would be possible to implement on top of the current pytest API. But I'm afraid it has not been done yet.

Answer (score 0):

pytest has an integration with [the native Python Debugger](http://docs.python.org/library/pdb.html). That might just give you exactly what you are looking for. It likely also integrates with your IDE if you use one.

Here is [very comprehensive overview](https://hackebrot.github.io/pytest-tricks/debug_test_failures/)

Comment: Using the debugger slows down the test. Even without running the debugger simple tests need 10 seconds since the project is big. 90% of the time is spent loading code collecting tests ... only 10% of the time is spent executing my test code.